# Limit of $a_{n+1}=a_{n}\cdot \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

Let $a_{n}$ be a recursive sequence such as: $\begin{cases}a_{1}=1\\
a_{n+1}=a_{n}\cdot \left( 1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \end{cases}$

I need to show that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=\infty$.

I showed that $a_{n}$ is increasing using induction, so we have two options:

1. $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=L$
2. $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=\infty$

I have tried assuming that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=L$ but I couldn't get to a contradiction.

Would appreciate some help!

Comment: Hint: Look at the sequence $b_n = \log a_n$. If $a_n$ had a finite limit, so would $b_n$, but $b_n$ looks like a sum, which you probably have more experience manipulating.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I don’t seem to understand what ‘$b_{n}$ looks like a sum’ means?

Comment: What would $b_3$ and $b_4$ be? Can you write them down explicitly? You'll see that the $a_n$s look like products, and the $b_n$s look like sums

Answer (score 5):

If $a_n =n, a_{n+1}=({n+1}/n) n=n+1$

since $a_1=1$ we can conclude that by induction $a_n=n$

Comment: Moreover, if we only knew $a_1 > 0$, we would obtain the same result, for if $\lambda:=a_1$, then $a_n=\lambda n$ for all $n$ and hence $a_n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @Don got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that  $ \frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}}{n}$ for all $n$. Therefore $\frac{a_{n}}{n}=\frac{a_{1}}{1}=1$. Thus $a_{n}=n$ and we are done!